# Correct way to keep writable database for an application

Tags: c#, database, wpf

I am creating a writable application database in `\AppData\Roaming\ProjectName` to keep authorization and cache.

1. So firstly, i have database.db in my project that i will copy to
   AppData, when App is started for the first time. But i have no
   idea how write a `Connection string` in `App.Config` that case.  Now it is:

   ```
   <connectionStrings> 
           <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\cache.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
       </connectionStrings>
   ```
2. Secondly, i am not sure, that i should use `App.Config` connection , but i`m going to change data a lot of times.
3. Thirdly, did i chose a right path to keep writable database
   or there are any of other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would reference a sqlite database in the appdata folder. I would not use the ConnectionStrings section of app.config. I would use the connection string builder and use `Environment` to get the path to the user's app data folder.

```
SqliteConnectionStringBuilder bldr = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder();

bldr.DataSource = System.IO.Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
    "your-program-folder-name",
    "your-database-name.db");

var sqliteConnection = new SqliteConnection(bldr.ConnectionString);
```

in #2 of your question I do not understand what you are referring to about changing data. Do you mean in the database or in the config file?

Regarding #3, you mention this database is used for authorization. If you put the database on the client machine you cannot lock it down. A user can figure out how to circumvent your security. So, if security is any kind of concern you need to put the back end on a restricted server and use a system that employs Role Based Access Control (or similar), and that is a large topic in itself.

Comment: Hi, @Crowcoder , thx for your answer. So about point  #2 , i mean that data in DB will be changed lots of times, not changing connection string. What about #3 , i have back end server and database would keep authorization data for logging in app. So the question that worries me is "is APPDATA the only place for placing writable database?" and "how to make it writable?".

Comment: @VladimirB since a sqlite database is just a file, you can put it anywhere the application has access to. Often it is in the same folder structure as the app but appdata works, it is your decision. It should be writable already, what are you experiencing that makes you ask how to make it writable?

Comment: thanks for all ,  nailed it , just pondered, sorry )

Comment: Oh , mate @Crowcoder , have you used `using System.Data.SQLite;` for it?

Comment: @VladimirB I tend to use Entity Framework with Sqlite projects, so this: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite. But you will be fine with that package.